# JSON document clustering using Machine Learning

Tags: java, json, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-science

I am trying to perform document clustering. Input format is a JSON String with various key and values of String and Number types. Depending on the types of keys present and the values i should be able to cluster the document with its own like types.

Ex: JSOn Document : 
`{"title":0, "brand":"Levis", "length":"28,30,32,34,36", "type":"Jeans"},
{"title":0, "brand":"Levis", "length":"28,30,32,34,36", "type":"Shirt"},
{"title":0, "brand":"Levis", "length":"28,30,32,34,36", "type":"Jeans"},
{"title":0, "brand":"Levis", "length":"28,30,32,34,36", "type":"Jeans"},
{"title":0, "brand":"Levis", "length":"28,30,32,34,36", "type":"Top"},
{"title":0, "Bname":"Brand1", "weight":"100", "type":"Top"},
{"title":0, "Bname":"Lee", "height":"2864", "type":"refrigerator"},
{"title":0, "brand":"Levis", "length":"28,30,32,34,36", "type":"Top"},
{"title":0, "Time":"Casio", "Price":"2000", "type":"watch"},
{"title":0, "brand":"Levis", "length":"28,30,32,34,36", "type":"Top"},
{"title":0, "brand":"Levis", "length":"28,30,32,34,36", "type":"Shirt"}`

based on the matching parameters, i want to cluster the documents.

I would like to know the approach and possible java machine learning library to perform this.

Till now i have understood Kmeans, DBSCAN in clustering, But i am not sure show to reduce the JSON string to vector and how to perform clustering on this results.

Answer (score -1):

I'd try to transform every JSON field into a column on CSV or some dataframe (as python pandas) paying attention to null values or not well formatted ones.

If you are working on Java, here is a [good article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/java-machine-learning/) of machine learning in that programming language. You could apply the same principles.

[Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) is a nice java tool to start trying supervised and unsupervised algorithms.

Good luck!